# For any function $v,$if $v \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question I want to prove is:

For any function $v,$if $v \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.

**Proof:**

Assume that $v \circ f$ is injective, then, by definition of injectivity for any $x,y$ in $D_{f}$, if $(v \circ f)(x) = (v \circ f)(y),$ then $x=y.$ but how this leads to the injectivity of $f,$ could anyone help me proof this please?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f(x)=f(y)$, then

$v(f(x))=v(f(y))$ , or

$(v\circ f) (x)=(v \circ f) (y)$;

Since $v \circ f$ is injective: $x=y$, and we are done .

Answer (score 1):

If possible let $f(x)=f(y)$ but $x \neq y$. Since  $v(f(x))=v(f(y))$ and $x \neq y$ we have  a contradiction to  the hypothesis.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the theorem stated with logic symbols:

$$[\space g(f(x))=g(f(y)) \implies f(x)=f(y) \space]_{if \space the \space composition \space is \space injective}\implies [\space f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y \space]_{then \space the \space inside \space function \space is \space injective} $$ 
$$\forall x,y\in D_f \space $$

We take that the whole antecedent is true, therefore $f(x)=f(y)$ is true as the hypothesis.

As @Kavi Rama Murty said, suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$ is true but the $x=y$ is wrong i.e. $x\ne y$ (you do this because the implication is only false if the antecedent is true and consequent is false; talking here about the third $\implies$).

But by the (contrapositive) definition of injectivity which goes: $\space x\ne y \implies f(x)\ne f(y)$ $\forall x,y\in D_f$ that leads to the contradiction of the hypothesis that $f(x)=f(y)$ is true, and therefore the theorem is valid.

P.S. The text in the subscript of the antecedent and consequent of the logical theorem statement are there for clarification purposes, you should not write those in rigorous proofs.